# could not find yew in stylist

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, yew

I'm new to rust and yew and trying to use `stylist` crate with yew but when I try to import `styled_components`, I am getting following error.

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `stylist::yew`
 --> src\lib.rs:2:14
  |
2 | use stylist::yew::styled_component;
  |              ^^^ could not find `yew` in `stylist`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `hello-yew` due to previous error
2022-11-22T16:30:53.476368Z ERROR  error
error from HTML pipeline
```

Has anyone seen this issue before?

I tried to delete previous stylist crates and tried to re-install the crate again but faced same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> ##### [Yew Integration](https://docs.rs/stylist/latest/stylist/#yew-integration)
>
> To enable yew integration. Enable feature yew_integration in Cargo.toml.
>
> You can create a style and use it with yew like this:
>
> ```rust
> use yew::prelude::*;
> use stylist::yew::styled_component;
>
> #[styled_component(MyStyledComponent)]
> fn my_styled_component() -> Html {
>     html! {<div class={css!("color: red;")}>{"Hello World!"}</div>}
> }
> ```